# Gradient descent underfits consistently

Tags: machine-learning, regression, octave, gradient-descent

I tried to fit a 6 degree polynomial in a training set and it's failing consistently. It underfits. I used the following code,

```
% X is feature scaled 
% Y is feature scaled too
function [J,grad,h]=costFunction(theta,X,Y,lambda)
  % theta is a (n+1)*1 vectorize
  % X is a m*(n+1) vector
  % Y is a m*1 vector
  h = X*theta;
  % h is a m*1 vector
  theta_r=[0;theta(2:end,:)];
  J=sum([h-Y].^2)+(lambda/(2*length(Y)))*theta_r'*theta_r;
  grad=zeros(length(theta),1);
  for j=1:length(theta)
    grad(j)=(1/length(Y))*sum((h-Y).*X(:,j));
  endfor
endfunction

function [cost_history,theta]=gradientDescent(theta,X,Y,alpha,num_iter,lambda)
  cost_history=zeros(num_iter,1);
  for i=1:num_iter
    [cost,grad,hyp]=costFunction(theta,X,Y,lambda);
    theta=theta*(1-((alpha*lambda)/length(Y)))-(alpha*grad);
    cost_history(i)=cost;
  endfor
endfunction

initial_theta=ones(size(X)(1,2),1);

[c_history,theta]=gradientDescent(initial_theta,X,Y,1,10000,0);

plot(X*theta,cx);  % cx is non-scaled feature X
hold on;
plot(cx,cy);       % cx,cy contain datasets
```

can you find any issues with this?

Comment: Have you tried messing around with your regularization parameter as well as your learning rate?

Comment: okay, let me try more and more, then I'll revert back sir.

Comment: @TathagataDey, you wrote `plot(X*theta,cx);`. I think it should be `plot(cx,X*theta);`.

Answer (score 0):

I found some issues:

In `costFunction`, you forgot to divide `J` by `2*length(Y)`.

In `gradientDescent`, you regularized theta(0) that shouldn't be regularized.

This is the corrected code:

```
function [J,grad,h]=costFunction(theta,X,Y,lambda)
  % theta is a (n+1)*1 vectorize
  % X is a m*(n+1) vector
  % Y is a m*1 vector
  h = X*theta;
  % h is a m*1 vector
  theta_r=[0;theta(2:end)];
  J=sum([h-Y].^2)/(2*length(Y))+(lambda/(2*length(Y)))*theta_r'*theta_r;
  grad=zeros(length(theta),1);
  for j=1:length(theta)
    grad(j)=(1/length(Y))*sum((h-Y).*X(:,j));
  endfor
endfunction

function [cost_history,theta]=gradientDescent(theta,X,Y,alpha,num_iter,lambda)
  cost_history=zeros(num_iter,1);
  for i=1:num_iter
    [cost,grad,hyp]=costFunction(theta,X,Y,lambda);
    theta(1)=theta(1)-(alpha*grad(1));
    theta(2:end)=theta(2:end)*(1-((alpha*lambda)/length(Y)))-(alpha*grad(2:end));
    cost_history(i)=cost;
  endfor
endfunction

initial_theta=ones(size(X, 2),1);

[c_history,theta]=gradientDescent(initial_theta,X,Y,1,10000,0);

plot(cx, X*theta);  % cx is non-scaled feature X
hold on;
plot(cx,cy);       % cx,cy contain datasets
```

I also recommend you to plot `c_history` as a function of `num_iter` to see if the gradient descent is converges or not. If not, but it still decreases, it means you need to increase the number of iterations. If it increases on each iteration, you need to decrease `alpha`. And if it converges but the cost is high, it means that `lambda` is too high or the degree of the polynomial is too less (as a result, your model will underfit the data).

I mean the plot should be `plot(c_history);`.

Hope it will fix your problem!